Two ways of attaching Galois representations to eigenforms?
Let $N$ be a positive integer, $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}$ and let $p$ be a prime number not dividing $N$. Let $f$ be a normalized Hecke newform of weight $k$, level $N$ and nebentypus $\varepsilon$. Then, there is a unique semisimple $p$-adic representation of $G_{\mathbb{Q}} := \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$
$$
\rho_f : G_{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p})
$$
such that for all prime $\ell \nmid pN$, $\rho_f$ is unramified at $\ell$ and for the Frobenius $\mathrm{Frob}_\ell$ at $\ell$, we have
$$
(*)  \quad \det(X- \rho_f(\mathrm{Frob}_\ell)) = X^2 - a_\ell(f) X + \varepsilon(\ell) \ell^{k-1}.
$$
Here I note that somewhere (e.g. Theorem 6.1 in Deligne-Serre's "Formes modulaires de poids 1" [link]) people require $\mathrm{Frob}_\ell$ to be the arithmetic Frobenius, but somewhere else (e.g. in Saito's "Modular forms and p-adic Hodge theory" [link]) people require that $\mathrm{Frob}_\ell$ to be the geometric Frobenius. The same condition (*) on the characteristic polynomials is imposed.
Question.
If we denote them by $\rho_f^{arith}$ and $\rho_{f}^{geom}$ for the respective kind of Frobenius elements, is there any relation between them? I thought for a while that they are dual to each other, but now this seems impossible... So, are they unrelated? I am asking this question mainly because in a survey paper by Laurent Berger on trianguline representations [link], he takes $\rho_f^{arith}|_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$, which is denoted by $V_p f$ now, and cites [Saito] (or rather, Scholl's "Motives for modular forms" [link] that [Saito] cites) to conclude the characteristic polynomial of the crystalline Frobenius $\phi$ on
$
D_{cris}((V_p f)^*) 
$
is
$$
X^2 - a_p(f)X + \varepsilon(p)p^{k-1}
$$
But this is what is expected for $D_{cris}(\rho_f^{geom}|_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}})$!
By $(V_p f)^*$ could Berger really mean the dual representation? I am very confused...
Any help or clarification of this situation would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

$\rho_f^{arith}$ and $\rho_f^{geom}$ are indeed dual one of each other, why does it seem impossible to you?

@Aphelli Thanks for confirming that. I was out of my mind...

Indeed, in general let $\rho_f^*$ denote the dual representation of $\rho$; then we have
$$
(\rho_f^{\text{arith}})^*(\operatorname{Frob}_\ell^{\text{geom}}) = \rho_f^{\text{arith}}((\operatorname{Frob}_\ell^{\text{geom}})^{-1}) = \rho_f^{\text{arith}}(\operatorname{Frob}\ell^{\text{arith}})
$$
So, the characteristic polynomial of $\rho_f^{\text{geom}}(\operatorname{Frob}_{\ell}^{\text{geom}})$ and that of $(\rho_f^{\text{arith}})^*(\operatorname{Frob}_\ell^{\text{geom}})$ coincide as
$$
X^2 - a_\ell(f) X + \varepsilon(\ell) \ell^{k-1}.
$$
for all $\ell \nmid pN$. We conclude that the dual of $\rho_f^{\text{arith}}$ is just $\rho_f^{\text{geom}}$.
